# How to enter street address directly in the code

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I want to use the google map api v3 like in this example https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

but without this input field

```
<div>
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
  <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
```

I want to specify the street address for example "75 wall st, new york" directly in the code. How do I do this?  Below is the code from that sample url. Anyone know what needs to be removed/added to this?

```
<link href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div>
<input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
<input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:90%;top:30px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could update the function to do this:

```
function codeAddress(address) {
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
```

}

And once you want to update the map, just call:

```
codeAddress('75 wall st, new york');
```

If you're using jQuery you could put this in your document ready function, or in another part of your code.